# CoreData: managedObjectContext not being created

Tags: cocoa-touch, core-data

I had to add core data to an existing project but I am having issues with the managedObjectContext...

in prefix.pch I have this:

```
#import <Availability.h>

#ifndef __IPHONE_5_0
#warning "This project uses features only available in iOS SDK 5.0 and later."
#endif

#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#endif
...
```

in my appDelegate.h I have this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppViewController.h"

#import "DDLog.h"
#import "DDASLLogger.h"
#import "DDFileLogger.h"
#import "DDTTYLogger.h"
#import "KIP_LogManager.h"


@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate> {

    DDFileLogger* fileLogger;

    /*coredata*/
    NSManagedObjectModel* managedObjectModel;
    NSManagedObjectContext* managedObjectContext;
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator* persistentStoreCoordinator;

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) AppViewController* viewController;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext* managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel* managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator* persistentStoreCoordinator;


- (void)setupLogging;

- (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory;
```

in appDelegate.m this:

```
@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = _managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = _persistentStoreCoordinator;

...

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //establish lumberjack logging
    [self setupLogging];

    DDLogVerbose(@"\n\n*********************\nNEW LOG SESSION\n**********************\n\n");

    //set root view controller
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.viewController = [[AppViewController alloc] init];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;

    self.viewController.managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;

    return YES;
}

...

    #pragma mark - CoreData Stack

    - (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
    {
        if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
            return _managedObjectContext;
        }

        NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
        if (coordinator != nil) {
            _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
            [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
        }

        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    // Returns the managed object model for the application.
    // If the model doesn't already exist, it is created from the application's model.
    - (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
    {
        if (_managedObjectModel != nil) {
            return _managedObjectModel;
        }
        NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"SPI_PAC" withExtension:@"momd"];
        _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
        return _managedObjectModel;
    }

    - (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {

        if (persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
            return persistentStoreCoordinator;
        }

        NSMutableString* strDocsDirector = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:[self applicationDocumentsDirectory]];
        [strDocsDirector appendString:@"/SPI_PAC.sqlite"];

        NSURL* storeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:strDocsDirector];

        NSError *error = nil;
        persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc]
                                      initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
        if(![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                                     configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {
            /*Error for store creation should be handled in here*/
        }

        return persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    - (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
        return [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    }
```

in the view controller, viewDidLoad I am logging the passed managedObjectContext and am getting null returned. Obviously I am missing something but not sure what?

In viewcontroller.h I have:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectModel* managedObjectModel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext* managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator* persistentStoreCoordinator;
```

and in the viewcontroller.m:

```
@synthesize managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext;
...
 DDLogVerbose(@"%@", managedObjectContext);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because the overridden getter for the MOC property isn't being called - you're accessing the instance variable instead.

Change:

`self.viewController.managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;`

To:

`self.viewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;`

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the -managedObjectContext method and step over each line, validating the results. Try changing `appendString:@"/SPI_PAC.sqlite"` to use `stringByAppendingPathComponent` instead.

Comment: Well, that could be a problem, the breakpoint never got called.

Comment: With the code you've supplied and assuming you've changed that line of code from my answer to use self.managedObjectContext, the breakpoint must be called. Is the project something small and something you can upload somewhere?

Comment: No, it's a enterprise project.

Answer (score 0):

After some (a whole day of some) trolling around The Google and here on SO I found a solution that works. I found the solution here:

[iOS Core Data App Delegate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420672/ios-core-data-app-delegate)

Instead of using Apple's canned core data stack I implemented everything myself.